spring authorization server storing access_token_value is empty
In spring oauth2 authorization server i store the token using JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService but the only problem is the access_token_value is empty in database.
I print it, and it show at 12 line which suppose to mapped to access_token_value
Link: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-authorization-server/blob/1.2.x/oauth2-authorization-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/oauth2/server/authorization/JdbcOAuth2AuthorizationService.java
Code
   private static final String COLUMN_NAMES = "id, "
            + "registered_client_id, "
            + "principal_name, "
            + "authorization_grant_type, "
            + "authorized_scopes, "
            + "attributes, "
            + "state, "
            + "authorization_code_value, "
            + "authorization_code_issued_at, "
            + "authorization_code_expires_at,"
            + "authorization_code_metadata,"
            + "access_token_value,"
            + "access_token_issued_at,"
            + "access_token_expires_at,"
            + "access_token_metadata,"
            + "access_token_type,"
            + "access_token_scopes,"
            + "oidc_id_token_value,"
            + "oidc_id_token_issued_at,"
            + "oidc_id_token_expires_at,"
            + "oidc_id_token_metadata,"
            + "refresh_token_value,"
            + "refresh_token_issued_at,"
            + "refresh_token_expires_at,"
            + "refresh_token_metadata,"
            + "user_code_value,"
            + "user_code_issued_at,"
            + "user_code_expires_at,"
            + "user_code_metadata,"
            + "device_code_value,"
            + "device_code_issued_at,"
            + "device_code_expires_at,"
            + "device_code_metadata";

    private static final String SAVE_AUTHORIZATION_SQL = "INSERT INTO " + TABLE_NAME
            + " (" + COLUMN_NAMES + ") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
 

    @Override
    public void save(OAuth2Authorization authorization) {
        Assert.notNull(authorization, "authorization cannot be null");
        OAuth2Authorization existingAuthorization = findById(authorization.getId());

        if (existingAuthorization == null) {
            insertAuthorization(authorization);
        }
        else {
            updateAuthorization(authorization);
        }
    }

    private void insertAuthorization(OAuth2Authorization authorization) {
        List<SqlParameterValue> parameters = this.authorizationParametersMapper.apply(authorization);
        for (SqlParameterValue parameter : parameters) {
            System.out.println("Key: " + parameter.getSqlType()+ ", Value: " + parameter.getValue());
        }


        try (LobCreator lobCreator = this.lobHandler.getLobCreator()) {
            PreparedStatementSetter pss = new LobCreatorArgumentPreparedStatementSetter(lobCreator,
                    parameters.toArray());
            this.jdbcOperations.update(SAVE_AUTHORIZATION_SQL, pss);
        }
    }


Print to check token exist,
this is the token Key: -4, Value: RknrVmtZ1nRMnpUWBNu776ml0FkFAuJQZCm5wT9tEIffy7hbKqUvh9lp0KD9HZTD2Xzg5NFV0HwO5iR1JTlMdDXTqIH
Key: 12, Value: 6ce24903-da4d-4d52-be4f-2b22ccb7bff1
Key: 12, Value: a08b138c-8b4b-4373-92c2-9c73f06f3869
Key: 12, Value: test60@gmail.com
Key: 12, Value: client_credentials
Key: 12, Value: [read]
Key: -4, Value: {"@class":"java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap"}
Key: 12, Value: null
Key: -4, Value: null
Key: 93, Value: null
Key: 93, Value: null
Key: -4, Value: null
Key: -4, Value: RknrVmtZ1nRMnpUWBNu776ml0FkFAuJQZCm5wT9tEIffy7hbKqUvh9lp0KD9HZTD2Xzg5NFV0HwO5iR1JTlMdDXTqIHbZrDtuA60N75CX4dQ7KjZf1DTynp1M7-8rvf8
Key: 93, Value: 2024-05-27 15:27:00.3731148
Key: 93, Value: 2024-05-27 17:27:00.3731148
Key: -4, Value: {"@class":"java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap","metadata.token.claims":{"@class":"java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableMap","sub":"conred60@gmail.com","aud":["java.util.Collections$SingletonList",["test60@gmail.com"]],"nbf":["java.time.Instant",1716794820.373114800],"scope":["java.util.LinkedHashSet",["[read]"]],"iss":["java.net.URL","http://localhost:8060"],"exp":["java.time.Instant",1716802020.373114800],"iat":["java.time.Instant",1716794820.373114800],"jti":"ffe0019c-30a4-4fda-8d52-51bc963a5c8d"},"metadata.token.invalidated":false}
Key: 12, Value: Bearer
Key: 12, Value: [read]
Key: -4, Value: null
Key: 93, Value: null
Key: 93, Value: null
Key: -4, Value: null
Key: -4, Value: null
Key: 93, Value: null
Key: 93, Value: null
Key: -4, Value: null
Key: -4, Value: null
Key: 93, Value: null
Key: 93, Value: null
Key: -4, Value: null
Key: -4, Value: null
Key: 93, Value: null
Key: 93, Value: null
Key: -4, Value: null

CREATE TABLE oauth2_authorization (
id varchar(100) NOT NULL,
registered_client_id varchar(100) NOT NULL,
principal_name varchar(200) NOT NULL,
authorization_grant_type varchar(100) NOT NULL,
authorized_scopes varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
attributes blob DEFAULT NULL,
state varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
authorization_code_value blob DEFAULT NULL,
authorization_code_issued_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
authorization_code_expires_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
authorization_code_metadata blob DEFAULT NULL,
access_token_value blob DEFAULT NULL,
access_token_issued_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
access_token_expires_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
access_token_metadata blob DEFAULT NULL,
access_token_type varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
access_token_scopes varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
oidc_id_token_value blob DEFAULT NULL,
oidc_id_token_issued_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
oidc_id_token_expires_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
oidc_id_token_metadata blob DEFAULT NULL,
refresh_token_value blob DEFAULT NULL,
refresh_token_issued_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
refresh_token_expires_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
refresh_token_metadata blob DEFAULT NULL,
user_code_value blob DEFAULT NULL,
user_code_issued_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
user_code_expires_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
user_code_metadata blob DEFAULT NULL,
device_code_value blob DEFAULT NULL,
device_code_issued_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
device_code_expires_at timestamp DEFAULT NULL,
device_code_metadata blob DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (id));
``


Kindly disregard this question, its being save, its look empty in mysql but its not by using this query CONVERT(access_token_value USING utf8) AS blob_text the value will show
